# Audience Sync in Sitecore CDP

Tags: cdp

Does anyone know about the difference between `presentation layer` and `speed layer` when selecting a data source for testing Audience sync in Sitecore `CDP`?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the **"Speed Layer Only"** option you will skip the additional Guest properties such as sessions, orders and segment memberships, i.e. you will get the empty arrays with no objects inside as follows:

```
...
"sessions": [],
"orders": [],
"segmentMemberships": [],
...
```